# Unique combinations of an array and number of occurences in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have an input array which is like this

```
all = [0 0;0 3;6 6;6 0;13 0;12 12;3 0;0 6;6 6];
```

I need to find unique combinations of each row and also the number of times this combination occurs e.g.

```
output1 = [0 0;0 3;0 6;0 13;6 6;12 12];
output2 = [1;2;2;1;2;1];
```

For getting the unique combination i used a combination of `sort` and `unique` functions in this way

```
unique(sort(all ,2),'rows');
```

The problem is getting the number of occurences of each combiantion. I tried using the `hist` function in this way

```
[a, b]= hist(all ,unique(sort(all ,2),'rows'));
```

But i got his error

> Error using histc Edge vector must be monotonically non-decreasing.
>
> Error in hist (line 121)
>       nn = histc(y,edgesc,1);

Can someone please help me to get the required outputs?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such cases, you don't want to work with the full rows. It is easier to work with the indices. `unique` already does the conversion to indices for you.

```
[output1,b,c]=unique(sort(all ,2),'rows')
output2=hist(c,1:numel(b))
```